# how to get data from resx file and put in xlf file in angilar

Tags: angular, resourcedictionary, resx

I have resx file which is in data value format. and I need to get this value and put it in xlf file on basis of data.

Resx file format

```
  <data name="familyMembersTravelling" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Family Members Travelling</value>
  </data>
```

XLF file format :

```
      <trans-unit id="manageaccountcomponent_success_userunlocked" datatype="html">
        <source>User has been unlocked successfully</source>
        <target>User has been unlocked successfully</target>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">app/app.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">22</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
```